# jQuery - accessing an item's ID on double click

Tags: jquery

This *should* be an easy one, but through all the research I've done on the net I just can't seem to find the solution!

I've currently got a sortable list using .sortable, and then a .bind event with a double click, with the bind event as follows:

```
$("#controlContainer").sortable({  
   blah blah  
})  
.bind('dblclick', function(event) {  
    alert($(event.eventData).attr('id'));  
});
```

My issue is the fact that the above doesn't work, I need to get the ID of whichever element has been double clicked, but can't find a way of accessing it.

Anyone with any solution? Would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try changing `event.eventData` to `event.target`.

```
.bind('dblclick', function(event) {  
    alert($(event.target).attr('id'));  
});
```

Comment: Thank you, solved issue! I'd already tried event.target, but the main issue was the ID not replicating once the item had been cloned on the sortable list.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/):

```
alert(event.target.id);
```

`event.data` is for accessing the data you pass to to `bind`.

Example:

```
.bind('click', {foo: 42}, function(event) {
    alert(event.data.foo);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
alert($(this).attr('id'));
```

Comment: If `#controlContainer` contained multiple chidren, `this` would be `#controlContainer` (the parent), and `event.target` would be the child.  Example: http://jsfiddle.net/9pTMC/